# Rearrange and aggregate in r

Tags: r, aggregate

I have the following data

```
> site<-c("A","A","A","B","B","C")  
> sample<-c("N","N","N","W","W","S")  
> effort<-c(2,2,2,1,1,3)  
> y<-c(1,0,1,1,0,1)  
> df<-data.frame(site,sample,effort,y)  
> df  
  site sample effort y  
1    A      N      2 1  
2    A      N      2 0  
3    A      N      2 1
4    B      W      1 1
5    B      W      1 0
6    C      S      3 1
```

And I would like to rearrange to get the minimum "effort" and sum "y" per sample and site.

To end up with the following

```
 site sample effort y
1    A      N      2 2
2    B      W      1 1
3    C      S      3 1
```

I have tried the following code

```
tr<-aggregate(.~site+sample,data=df, FUN=function(df) c(m=min(df), n=length(df)))
> tr
  site sample effort.m effort.n y.m y.n
1    A      N        2        3   0   3
2    C      S        3        1   1   1
3    B      W        1        2   0   2
```

This is nearly what I am looking for but is there a better way to do this and how should I deal with zeros in the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plyr`

```
 require(plyr)
 ddply(df, c("site", "sample"), summarize,
       min_eff = min(effort), sum_y = sum(y))

   site sample min_eff sum_y
1    A      N       2     2
2    B      W       1     1
3    C      S       3     1
```

In your example, there's a one-to-one correspondence between site and sample. This approach will work for every pairwise distinct combination. As to

> How should I deal with zeros in the data?

How do you want to deal with them? What are your concerns?

Comment: That is perfect thank you.  I'd upvote this but seem unable to as it's my first question.

Comment: Previously when I tried to sum "y" I was getting a total number including the zeros but this method is what I was looking for.

Comment: @user3348711 You'll be able to upvote soon. Check out the other answer(s) too, and if you're satisfied mark one as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark next to it. That way people will know you aren't still waiting for more answers.

Comment: @user3348711 And do compare the `plyr` solution to the `dplyr` solution to note the parallels, the packages have the same author, but `dplyr` is newer and much faster (noticeable on big data sets).

Answer (score 2):

An answer using powerful `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

df %.%
    group_by(site,sample) %.%
    select(site, sample) %.%
    summarise (
        mineff = min(effort),
        y = sum(y))

  site sample mineff y
1    C      S      3 1
2    A      N      2 2
3    B      W      1 1
```